# Determine whether app compiled with or without _DEBUG macro

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have the app (executable file), but I do not have source code of that app. I can launch this app.
I need to know is it release or debug build.

Is there any way in Windows to programmatically determine that app was compiled with `_DEBUG` macro?

P.S.
`CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent` can check existence of attached debugger process. This is not what I need.

Comment: Unless you have debug information available that can tell you what macros was defined when building, then no there is no way.

Comment: I found several articles 'how to debug release build' with instructions how to do that. And I figured out that for some apps list of loaded DLLs very different for release/debug build. Therefore I assume debuggers can distinguish release/debug build.

Comment: You can check if it links with the debug or release versions of the standard C library DLL (if it wasn't linked statically). The exact DLL names depend on the Visual Studio version.

Comment: A debugger does not care if the executable was built with Debug or Release compile options.  It just gets a little lame at displaying useful debug info.  Since you don't have any source code and probably no .pdb either, this really does not matter.  You'll be staring at machine code without any real idea what it does and you of course have no hope of actually fixing any bugs.

Comment: What interjay said.  Run `dumpbin.exe /imports YourApp.exe | findstr /i \.dll` to see what DLLs are imported.  A debug build will *likely* (but not guaranteed to) import some variation of MSVCRT**D**.dll or VCRUNTIME**D**.dll.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by sniffing it in with some of the most basic data,
two such examples are the bin strings and application headers;

- In some cases the strings might hold telltale signs for example the following for the same executable compiled with and without:

without 
`<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT`"

With`<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT"`

(Possibly also id the compiler?)

You can extract the strings with any of the following options: Open the exe in VS and look at the RCDATA, open the exe in a hex editor, GUI tools such as BinText, strings utility [MinGW binutils (windows)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/binutils/binutils-2.25.1/) and many more options

- Going over the PE header (Using VS dumpbin.exe for example). One hint that i did notice in the past was that the checksum field in the OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES was set only in release builds. If you are trying to do so for a file on the disk the PE format is well documented and you should be able to "disassemble" it to get the fields. It should also be possible for an executable loaded into memory as a running process once you find the base address of the image loaded into memory (for example by using the the [tool help snapshot API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686849(v=vs.85).aspx))

As i said these might give away the answer or if not hopefully give some leads to on with.